# Global array in C header?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-c++, global-variables

Okay, strange question time!

I'm refactoring some old C++ code that declares a bunch of arrays like so:

```
static SomeStruct SomeStructArray[] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {NULL, 0, 0}
}
```

And so forth. These are scattered about in the source files, and are used right where they're declared.

However, I would like to move them into a single source file (mostly because I've come up with a way of auto-generating them). And, of course, I naively try to make a header for them:

```
static SomeStruct SomeStructArray[];
```

Actually, even I know that's wrong, but here's the compiler error anyway:

```
error C2133: 'SomeStructArray' : unknown size    arrays.h
error C2086: 'SomeStruct SomeStructArray[]' : redefinition    arrays.cpp
```

So, I guess, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to put the arrays themselves all in one file (and apparently access them from other files) you need to *remove* the `static` from the definitions (which makes them visible only inside the same translation unit (i.e., file)).

Then, in your header you need to add an `extern` to each declaration.

Finally, of course, you'll need to ensure that when you have an array of `SomeStruct` (for example), that the definition of `SomeStruct` is visible before you attempt to define an array of them.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense. Also, yeah, I omitted the irrelevant parts of the code, since they're irrelevant :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

.h file:

```
extern SomeStruct SomeStructArray[];
```

.cpp file:

```
extern SomeStruct SomeStructArray[] = {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6},
  {NULL, 0, 0}
}
```

Comment: Why `extern` on the array itself? Doesn't it get `extern`'d from the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file and put this in it:

```
extern SomeStruct SomeStructArray[];
```

then put your existing code into a source file (not a header file):

```
SomeStruct SomeStructArray[] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {NULL, 0, 0}
}
```

And the downside, you can't get the size of the array in other source files:

```
size_t size = sizeof SomeStructArray; // doesn't work in any source file apart
                                      // from the one defining the array.
```

You could add extra variables to get around this.

This was tested using DevStudio2k5.

Comment: This is not true, my compiler (even in Standard conforming mode) says:
*error: ‘SomeStructArray’ was declared ‘extern’ and later ‘static’*

Comment: Ah, I see what I've done. I didn't include the header declaring the array into the source file containing the definition of the array. Fixed it.